# How can I install UrlScan on an Azure Web Role?

Tags: azure

Well, title more or less says it all. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebPI to install it from a startup script. For instance:

```
cd "%~dp0"
md appdata
reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%~dp0appdata" /f 
WebPICmdLine.exe /accepteula /Products:UrlScan
reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%USERPROFILE%%\AppData\Local /f 
exit /b 0
```

Note: This script is borrowed from Steve Marx (see original [here](http://things.smarx.com/#Install%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203)).